# How do I post something using cURL that starts with `@`?

Tags: curl

The command

```
curl http://localhost/ --data @hello
```

will try to read from file `hello`. How do I escape the `@` symbol?

Comment: @stArdustͲ: not in curl 7.36.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without trying to find out more about the internals of curl, I would suggest just piping into it:

```
printf @hello | curl http://localhost/ --data @-
```

As @ulrich-schwarz suggested in a comment, you could also use
`--data @<(echo @hello)` if it's more convenient (not all shells
support this syntax).

Looking at the source code for curl-7.41.0, I don't see any way to escape a `@` sign to prevent interpretation as a file name:

```
if('@' == is_file) {
  /* a '@' letter, it means that a file name or - (stdin) follows */

  if(curlx_strequal("-", p)) {
    file = stdin;
    set_binmode(stdin);
  }
  else {
    file = fopen(p, "rb");
    if(!file)
      warnf(config,
            "Couldn't read data from file \"%s\", this makes "
            "an empty POST.\n", nextarg);
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

So, unfortunately, it looks like we are stuck with the piping solution above.

Comment: In case of multiple such items: `curl http://localhost:8080 --data @<(echo '@hello')` or variations thereon should also work.

Comment: Thanks, @UlrichSchwarz, I integrated this solution into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The data is sent with the content type [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1). In principle, `%40` should be decoded to `@`, so the following command should send equivalent data:

```
curl http://localhost/ --data %40hello
```

However this may or may not work depending on whether the server-side application actually performs URL decoding. If it expects unencoded data, which is fairly common when the application didn't expect the data to contain any special character, the application may interpret this as `%40hello`.

If the application doesn't do decoding, [pipe the data to curl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193615).

Comment: That didn't work for me. :-/

Answer (score 0):

From curl [man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-raw):

> `--data-raw <data>`
>
> (HTTP) This posts data similarly to `-d`, `--data` but without the special
>   interpretation of the @ character.

So your command should be